# how to quantify variation in continuous outcome for samples matched on continuous predictor

Tags: regression, references, censoring, matching, variability

I have a data consisting of about 2 million cases.  Cases are scored on some (overdispersed) predictor we'll call "employee performance."  I would like to match or pool cases with the same score or perhaps a highly similar score (i.e. within a point or two of each other).

The outcome is continuous and is observed for only about 25% of the dataset.  Think of this outcome like a salary bonus - most employees don't receive one.  Some do, and of those that do, some receive very very large ones (so the variable is positively skewed and over dispersed).  Technically, the variable is censored on the top end (but we can ignore this complexity) and on the bottom it's censored at 0 (i.e. no bonus).  I've used Heckman/Tobit and hurdle models on this outcome in the past but the focus of those analyses was different than the present case.

The observations are clustered within about 20 different firms.  I want to compare the variability in bonuses within each firm for employees that match on the performance metric score.  I'd also like to examine variability in receiving bonuses (again for individuals with the same score).  I can't wrap my head around how to do this, I'm not a statistician and this doesn't fit neatly into the standard regression framework (even interquartile range regression).  The big picture here is that I'm interested in fairness, specifically consistency.  In terms of receiving the bonus (or not) this is an issue of concordance vs. discordance.  In terms of the amount of the bonus, I'm not sure how to describe it, maybe median absolute deviation...???

I'm wondering if this is something that could be done with ROC analysis or the Gini-coefficient.  I can't quite see how that would work, however.  And I really want to utilize a matching framework since all observations are scored on this universal performance metric that is supposed to be the basis for determining who gets a bonus and who doesn't as well as the amount of the bonus (the score is used to calculate a 'suggested bonus').

As an added layer of complexity, I'm working with non-math oriented practitioners who will view complex statistics with suspicion.  Thus I really want a robust and intuitive framework, ideally non-parametric given that both the outcome and predictor are badly skewed and overdispersed.

I know this is a tall order, but any suggestions, thoughts, articles/ or texts would be helpful.